# Experimenting with key volatility in redis

Tags: redis

Need to clear a concept about redis `EXPIRE` operation.

Imagine I write the following code:

```
 HMSET myself name "Sam" age "21"
 EXPIRE myself 60
```

This sets the hash `myself={'name':'Sam','age':'21'}` (using python dictionary to illustrate the concept). Moreover, it sets `myself` to expire after 60 seconds.

What happens to the `EXPIRE` setting if I perform a couple of operations on `myself`? E.g.:

```
HINCRBY myself age 1
HSET myself gender f
```

Will `EXPIRE` remain intact, or will it be removed? And taking it a step further, do us redis coders have any control on whether `EXPIRE` stays or not in such cases?

Comment: Redis has [ttl](https://redis.io/commands/ttl) command, which will return you the remaining life-time of a key :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expire will remain, and the TTL will continue to decrease.

From [Redis doc](https://redis.io/commands/expire) :

> altering the field value of a hash with HSET (...) will leave the timeout untouched

As Maurice Meyer said above, you can use `TTL myself` to get the remaining Time To Live of the key mysef, and so use it for your experiments.